# Extreme django performance issues after launching

Tags: python, mysql, django, performance, apache

We have recently launched a django site which amongst other things, has a screen representing all sorts of data. A request to the server is sent every 10 seconds to get new data. The average response size is 10kb.

The site is working on approx. 30 clients, meaning every client sends a get request every 10 seconds.

When locally testing, responses came back after 80ms. After deployment with 30~ users, we're taking up to 20 seconds!!

So the initial thought is that my code sucks. I went through all my queries and did everything i can to optimize then and reduce calls to the database  (which was hard, nearly everything is somwething like object.filter(id=num) and my tables have less thab 5k rows atm...)

But then i noticed the same issue occurs in the admin panel! Which is clearly optimized and doesn't have my perhaps inefficient code, since I didn't write it. Opening the users tab takes 30 seconds at certain requests!!

So, what is it? Do I argue with the company  sysadmins and demand a better server? They say we dont need better hardware (running on dual core 2.67ghz and 4gb ram, which isnt a lot, but still shouldn't be THAT slow)

Doesn't the fact that the admin site is slow imply that this is a hardware issue?

Comment: How did you deploy that Django site? Which web server is up front? How is the web server dealing with single requests?

Comment: It is quite difficult to make a performance auditing in SO since the problem can come from every layer. The best you can do is to test layer by layer, and come back with more accurate information on your problem once the problematic layer is identified.

Comment: Maybe that's a stupid question but ... Did you switch off DEBUG option in your settings ?

Comment: 1. Yes, debug is off. 2. I'm using apache and mysql. 3. As for the other questions - I am very inexperienced in the scaling & performance fields. Aside from checking my queries, and making sure there isn't anything stupid, i'd really  appreciate if somebody could suggest further tests i could do...